# An empty pipe element is not allowed

Tags: powershell

I understand how to make it as subexpression when using `foreach` loop or use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`. But nothing is working. I have to `Export-Csv` the below output.

```
foreach ($i in $a) {
  Write-Host $i (Get-Mailbox -Database $i -ResultSize Unlimited).Count
} | Export-Csv "c\users\...\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Or,

```
$a | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host $_ (Get-Mailbox -Database $_ -ResultSize Unlimited).Count
} | Export-Csv "c\users\...\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: so why are you using `write-host`?

Comment: my aim is to bring both the database names and counts in one line for each of the datases in $a.
DB02  19
DB03  40
DB04  20

my whole aim is bring this output and sort on the basis of count and then select first $number, which can be 10 or 20, etc.

Comment: The pipe is empty because you're not outputting anything to the pipe.  `Write-Host` sends it directly to the console ignoring the pipe.  Can you give an example of what you expect to see in the CSV file?

Comment: @RyanBemrose No, the problem is using a loop statement `foreach($i in $a){...}` followed by a pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the error "*An empty pipe is not allowed*" because the `foreach ($x in $y)` statement does not output a pipeline.  When you need to use pipeline output, use the cmdlet version `$y | Foreach-Object` instead.

The second problem is that your code is not outputting anything to the pipe.  `Write-Host` sends output directly to the console, ignoring the pipe.  To output to the pipeline, use `Write-Output`, or simply use the object as a statement and PowerShell will implicitly call `Write-Output`.

It's not clear what you expect to see in the CSV file, but the following code will use `PSCustomObject` to output a CSV with two columns.  The first is an element of `$a` and the second is the count of your `get-mailbox` call.  Note this is split over multiple lines for readability.

```
$a | foreach-object {
  [PSCustomObject]@{
     first=$_
     second=(get-mailbox -database $_ -resultsize unlimited).count
  }
} | export-csv "c\users\...\test.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: *An empty pipe element is not allowed.* is the syntax error. it happens due to not have command at all (`<#no command here#> | Command`). Having pipeline command, which not output anything to pipeline, is not violate PowerShell rules at all (`Write-Host Message | Command`).

Comment: Have to agree with @PetSerAl here, this answer is wildly misleading (although the proposed solution is perfectly good)

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I have updated the explanation.  I clearly wasn't thinking in the wee hours of last night.

Comment: Thanks for resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Write-Output`instead of `Write-Host`. `Write-Host` directly sends the output to the console, and not to the pipe. `Write-Ouput` is designed for pipe-usage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using `Write-Output` is unnecessary.  Any statement that outputs a value is implicitly sent to `Write-Output`.  The following two statements are identical: `Write-Output "hello"` and `"hello"`